# Cancel AWSS3 TransferUtility Upload task on button tap

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, awss3transferutility

My requirement is to cancel upload when ever user wishes.
I'm following TransferUtility document to setup and upload video, show progress, retains state even if app is in background. I couldn't find any way to cancel the uploadTask.

```
{
let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
let  transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
var completionHandler : AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
var uploadTask : AWSTask<AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask>?
let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()

}


func startUpload() {

uploadTask = transferUtility.uploadFile((uploadRequest?.body)!,
                                   bucket: (uploadRequest?.bucket)!,
                                   key: (uploadRequest?.key)!,
                                   contentType: "video/mov",
                                   expression: expression,
                                   completionHander: completionHandler).continue({ (task) -> AnyObject! in if let error = task.error {
                                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    }
                                    if let _ = task.result {

                                    }
                                    return nil;
                                   }) as? AWSTask<AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask>


}
```

I want to know which continue block i should use on the task and how to perform something like uploadTask.cancel() just the way we use for TransferManager task.

Answer (score 5):

From the AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html) you should use `AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest` as point to cancel upload request.

So simply:

```
uploadRequest.cancel()
```

If you would like to cancel `AWSS3TransferUtility` task. You should work with them directly.

Use method `enumerateToAssignBlocks` to fetch all active `AWSS3TransferUtility` tasks. Or directly by using method `getUploadTasks()`.

```
AWSS3TransferUtility.default().getUploadTasks()
```

After you get all active upload tasks simply use `taskIdentifier` of each task to find what task it is. And yes you should store `taskIdentifier` of task that you would like to cancel before.

Example of the cancel method.

```
static func cancel(taskIdentifier: UInt) {
        _transferUtility.enumerateToAssignBlocks(forUploadTask: { (uploadTask:AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask, progress:AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<(@convention(block) (AWSS3TransferUtilityTask, Progress) -> Void)?>?, error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<(@convention(block) (AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask, Error?) -> Void)?>?) in
            if uploadTask.taskIdentifier == taskIdentifier {
                uploadTask.cancel()
            }
        }, downloadTask: nil)
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried to fetch all tasks active now, but i couldn't run a loop and cancel all tasks. I want to know the line of code that cancels the AWSTask.

Comment: You should cancel each task separately

Comment: Since i'm saving task instance as 'uploadTask' can i cancel like uploadTask.result.cancel() ?? But that's not happening.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk I have the same issue with AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask. I can not cancel Upload Task so can you please help me out. THANKS.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Can you please let me know If I have multiple multipart files uploading simultaniously how can I get the taskIdentifier to cancel particular file upload?

Answer (score 3):

I use theese two helper methods when I want to cancel one specific upload request or all upload requests:

```
static func cancelAllUploads() {
    AWSS3TransferUtility.default().enumerateToAssignBlocks(forUploadTask: { (uploadTask, progress, error) in
        uploadTask.cancel()
    }, downloadTask: nil)
}

static func cancelAllUploads(withTaskId taskId: UInt) {
    AWSS3TransferUtility.default().enumerateToAssignBlocks(forUploadTask: { (uploadTask, progress, error) in
        if uploadTask.taskIdentifier == taskId {
            uploadTask.cancel()
        }
    }, downloadTask: nil)
}
```

Comment: How i can get taskId when i start uploadtask?

Comment: @chiragshah: after you call the async task `let uploadTask = AWSS3TransferUtility.default().uploadFile(...`, you can get the taskId by calling `uploadTask.result?.taskIdentifier`